# What is the order of (log n)/ (log(log n))?

Tags: big-o

What is the order of `f=(log n)/ (log(log n))`?

Is `f= O(log n)`? Why is that?

And what is order of `h=(log n) * (log log n)`?

Is it also `h= O(log n)`? And why is that correct?

Comment: It's not my homework! So how should I ask my questions?

Comment: How did you arrive at your proposed answers, at least one of which is wrong?

Comment: Yes you right. Perhaps the second guess is not correct.  How can I edit my question?

Comment: Not sure you can edit with your reputation; if not, you could add comment(s), or delete & ask again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. > Is `f= O(log n)`?

   Yes
2. > Is it also `h= O(log n)`?

   No

**Proof:**

Use the **formal definition**:

> f(n) = O(g(n)) means there are positive constants c and n0, such that 0 ≤ f(n) ≤ cg(n) for all n ≥ n0. The values of c and n0 must be fixed for the function f and must not depend on n.

1. `f = O(logn) <=> (log n)/ (log(log n)) = O(logn)`

   So, you need to find `c` and `n0` such that `0 ≤ (log n)/ (log(log n)) ≤ c*logn` for all `n ≥ n0`. Let's suppose that the logarithm base is `b` (it doesn't matter actually, but you can consider `b` in `{2,e,10}`). If you choose `c=1` and `n0=b^b^2`, `0 ≤ (log n)/ (log(log n)) ≤ logn` for all `n ≥ b^b^2`.

   - the first part is true, because `log n ≥ log b^b^2 = b^2 ≥ 0` and `log(log n) ≥ log(log b^b^2) = 2 ≥ 0`
   - the second part is also true, because it becomes `log(log n) ≥ 1` and `log(log n) ≥ log(b^2) = 2 ≥ 1`.
2. Similarly to the first proof, you need to prove that you can't choose `c` and `n0` so that `(log n) * (log(log n)) ≤ c*logn` is true for all `n ≥ n0`. And for a big `n` it becomes `(log(log n)) ≤ c` because `log n` cannot be `0`. And it's obvious that you can't choose a `c` because it won't be true for `n > b^b^c`.